# How to generate a json file from dataframe concatenating columns

Tags: json, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have this dataframe:

```
name        age
Paul        12
Andres      13
Caroline    14
Justin      15
```

I want to create a `json file` with the structure below:

```
{"NAME":["Paul","Andres","Caroline","Justin"], "NAME-AGE" :{"Paul":12,"Andres":13,"Caroline":14,"Justin":15},"VERSION":1}
```

I know I can use df.to_json() but I'm having a hard time to get the exactly output I want, including the version information.

What's the best approach to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
d = {'NAME': df['name'].to_list(),
     'NAME-AGE': df.set_index('name')['age'].to_dict(),
     'VERSION': 1,
    }

import json

out = json.dumps(d)
```

output:

```
'{"NAME": ["Paul", "Andres", "Caroline", "Justin"], "NAME-AGE": {"Paul": 12, "Andres": 13, "Caroline": 14, "Justin": 15}, "VERSION": 1}'
```

Comment: Now I am trying to save it to disk using: ` import json with open('patients.json', 'w') as f: json.dump(out, f)` but the .json file created has a lot of `\` symbol.  Is this the correct way to save it?

Comment: Then use `json.dump` for direct file access ;)